# How can I stop edge running at startup on my laptop

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, autostart

I just purchased an HP laptop running Windows 10.  Every time I Restart or Waken or Unlock, edge starts up with some stupid page running some search in Bing.

1. It is not in Startup Apps
2. `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` is empty
3. It is not in `Task Manager -> Startup`
4. From Google search, `Startup Boost` is off

Comment: Look in Autoruns (SysInternals), and look for HP apps starting Edge.  Not starting here (Lenovo machines)

Comment: This could be anything on the system requesting a HTTP protocol handler non specific. Switch the default for everything to chrome, and reboot, if it opens chrome then,that is the case. To see what may be starting it, you can log startup with process monitor which should tell the story. https://service.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413798945811-Use-Process-Monitor-to-create-real-time-event-logs

Comment: Use [Autoruns for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the default screen saver on the lock screen.  A click almost anywhere on it opens up Bing with a description of that image.  Multiple clicks before logging on open multiple tabs.

The solution was to change the default setting

- Open Settings
- Personalization
- Lock Screen
- Background (Change it to anything other than **Windows Spotlight**)

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. It came back the next day.